# Eclipse: "Simple" Template Problem with ${word_selection}

Tags: eclipse, templates

i got a (hopefully) simple problem with a Code Template on Eclipse. I try to use a Code Template to surround a word with somehing. The Replacement is nearly successful, but i have a problem with handling the selected word.

My task is to select "save " on this example

```
<button type="submit">save</button>
```

and want to have

```
<button type="submit"><?= $this->_('save') ?></button>
```

The problem is, that i got this after replacement

```
<button type="submit">save<?= $this->_('save') ?></button>
```

Is there a possibility to remove the selected word after using a code template? I am thankful for every help i get. Smile

I forgot, the template looks like this:

```
<?= $$this->_('${word_selection}') ?>${cursor}
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this question is somewhat old, but I came across the same idea in Java for adding String constants by simply typing the desired name and then replace it with a template, like this for example:

type `VALUE` and get it replaced with `private static final String VALUE = "VALUE";`

I use eclipse 3.6 and got it working with the following template:

`private static final String ${word_selection} = "${word_selection}";`

Then I do the following steps:

1. type `VALUE`
2. select it by double-clicking and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>
3. enter first few chars for the template name in the opened proposal pop-up and select the template (see image below)

   [image: eclipse template]
4. hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

And the result is this:

[image: replaced word with definition]

Maybe this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Using templates and the `${line_selection}` or `${word_selection}` variables, Eclipse (Helios, 3.6.1 here) always seems to insert the rendered template *after* the text you initially selected.

I've experienced this myself (in the HTML editor) while trying to implement a similar 'Surround with Tag' template, and gave up and reverted to using Ctrl+1 (after selecting text), and using '**Surround with new element...**'. Unfortunately this workaround doesn't help you much w/ PHP.

Possible bug report?

Comment: I though my bad feeling come true and it is realy not possible to use code templates in this special case, damn. :)

Did you know, if there is a possiblity to define own "Surround with" parts in HTML Editor, to hack the wanted effect in a way?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You are supposed to be able to do this with ${line_selection} but it doesn't seem to work in HTML mode. See this blog post: http://www.vasanth.in/2008/08/12/eclipse-tip-custom-surround-with/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help... i recognized, that what i need is not really possible in eclipse. Too bad. :/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem in jsp page. I resolved this issue by using 4 or more characters to select the template in eclipse. And I got the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same. I came to

```
${cursor}${word_selection} = <%= ${word_selection} %>
```

to be able with a CTRL + backspace to easily delete duplicated word_selection.

So in your example

```
<button type="submit">${cursor}<?= $$this->_('${word_selection}') ?></button>
```

will produce :

```
<button type="submit">save(<-- cursor is here)<?= $$this->_('save') ?></button>
```

Then after keyboard deletion :

```
<button type="submit">save(<-- cursor is here)<?= $$this->_('save') ?></button>
```

Drawback for you is that you need to move the outter HTML in the template to be able to place cursor inside after completion.