# using ${word_selection} in Eclipse JDT

Tags: eclipse, templates

How I can use ${word_selection} in my Java templates ?
I have inserted it, but I could not get it work.

I copy pasted a word before its usage, but the selected word did not appear in result of the template.

What did I wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not appear in result of the template"? Do you want to use the word you have copied for ${word_selection} in the template?

Answer (score 1):

I think it works that way that `${word_selection}` is being replaced by a selected word in your editor.

I have just posted an answer to a similar question over here: [Eclipse: “Simple” Template Problem with ${word_selection}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15949395/1592796)

Maybe this can be helpful for you.